# How do I align generated textures?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have this metal texture seen on the screenshot that is used on the pillar and on the support beam, but it is misaligned on the support beam.
[image]

Its made using a noise texture and color ramp [image]
Is there a way to have it align properly with both objects using the same material?
(Pillard and support beam are separate objects)

Comment: are you sure that the transforms are applied for your support beams (scale and rotation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use a wave texture to better illustrate what's happening:

[image: wave texture]

[image: plane with texture applied]

Duplicate the plane and add a diagonal strip to it with the knife tool:

[image: showing diagonal strip edges]

That plane will have exactly the same pattern:

[image: The same pattern]

It's easier to see if we remove the corners of the second plane:

[image: plane and strip showing same wave orientation]

I would fix this by UV unwrapping the support beam and use the UV output of the texture coordinates.  Here's the UV Map

[image: UV map for my simple example]

Don't forget to change the Texture Coordinate to UV

[image: texture coordinates swapped to UV]

and the result

[image: result]

Comment: ohh thank you that did the trick. I didnt know the UV map affects procedular generated stuff, thought it would only affect if when I put a direct image in there for mapping